# Angular pass multiple templates to Component

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template

I'm trying to create a component that accepts multiple templates as inputs. This is the example I have:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'data-list',
    styles: [
        require('./data-list.component.scss')
    ],
    template: `
        <ng-template
            *ngFor="let item of itemsData"
            ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="[item]" [ngForTemplate]="itemTemplate"
        ></ng-template>
    `
})

export class DataListComponent {
    @Input() itemsData: any[];
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
}
```

As you can see it's a fairly simple component that I'm trying out. This component simply accepts the data of the items to be displayed as well as the template of the item. This component can be used like so:

```
<data-list [itemsData]="data">
    <ng-template let-item>
        <h1>{{ item.header }}</h1>
        <div>{{ item.content }}</div>
    </ng-template>
</data-list>
```

As shown above I'm passing the template using `ng-content` which is then read by the `DataListComponent` with `@ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;`.

My question is whether it is possible to pass multiple templates to a component.

As an example one would pass the template for the items, but a different template is needed in case it's the first item. This would mean that the check of the first item would be made in the `DataListComponent` but then use a template specified by the component using it.

**Simple example:**

[image]

I can do something like so to cater for this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'data-list',
    styles: [
        require('./data-list.component.scss')
    ],
    template: `
        <span *ngFor="let item of itemsData; let i = index" >
            <ng-template *ngIf="i > 0; else nextTmpl"
                ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="[item]" [ngForTemplate]="itemTemplate"
            ></ng-template>
        </span>
        <ng-template #nextTmpl>
            Next
        </ng-template>
    `
})
```

However like so the "Next Template" is not specified by the component using the `DataListComponent` and therefore will always be the same template.

Comment: Did you mean `ngIf`?

Comment: Yep sure, I've updated the question to try to explain better what I mean.

Comment: If you're looking to name your templates on the 'outside' this is a better way https://stackoverflow.com/a/66172026/16940

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I solved this same issue by using the string selector available to the ContentChild decorator.

You will need to specify template variables when using your data-list component:

```html
<data-list [itemsData]="data">
    <ng-template #firstItemTemplate let-item>
        <h1 style="color:red;">{{ item.header }}</h1>
        <div>{{ item.content }}</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #standardTemplate let-item>
        <h1>{{ item.header }}</h1>
        <div>{{ item.content }}</div>
    </ng-template>
</data-list>
```

Then, inside your data-list component class, assign the template variables to local variables on the component:

```js
@Input() itemsData: any[];
@ContentChild('firstItemTemplate') firstItemTemplate: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
@ContentChild('standardTemplate') standardTemplate: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
```

After this, you'll be able to render the passed-in templates from your data-list component.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'data-list',
    styles: [
        require('./data-list.component.scss')
    ],
    template: `
        <span *ngFor="let item of itemsData; let i = index" >
            <ng-template *ngIf="i == 0; else nextTmpl"
                ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="[item]" [ngForTemplate]="firstItemTemplate"
            ></ng-template>
            <ng-template #nextTmpl 
                ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="[item]" [ngForTemplate]="standardTemplate"
            ></ng-template>
        </span>
    `
})
```

Comment: That's a smart way of doing it! Looks pretty neat :) I'll be sure to try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: This worked well, thank you. Only thing I had to add was `*ngIf="i > 0"` for the `#nextTmpl` I know it's a bit weird but in the next template I was getting both templates.

Comment: How do you pass the index though?

Comment: @Wei-jye To pass the index through, I'd recommend changing the `data-list` component template to use `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="standardTemplate; context: { item: item, index: i }"></ng-container>` rather than the current `<ng-template ngFor...` approach.  It might be worth making a new question, depending on what all you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'data-list',
    styles: [
        require('./data-list.component.scss')
    ],
    template: `
        <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="itemsData" [ngForTemplate]="itemTemplate"></ng-template>
    `
})

export class DataListComponent {
    @Input() itemsData: any[];
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
}
```