# Angular @ContentChildren not working with directive as selector

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

In my angular project, I an trying to enumerate the `ng-template` elements defined in the HTML template, based on a Directive.

I am trying to follow the example given in the answer by Aleš Doganoc in the answer to the question:
[Get multiple ng-template ref values using contentChildren in angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185318/get-multiple-ng-template-ref-values-using-contentchildren-in-angular-5)

I am using Angular 17.2, which is much newer than the version used in the original answer.

The directive is defined as:

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tableColumn]'
})
export class TableColumnDirective 
{
  constructor(public readonly template: TemplateRef<any>) { }
  @Input('tableColumn') columnName: string = '';
}
```

My app.component.html contains:

```
<my-table>
  <ng-template tableColumn="firstname" let-firstname>
    <h1>this template is for column firstName</h1>
 </ng-template>
 <ng-template tableColumn="lastName" let-lastname>
    <h1>this template is for column lastName</h1>
 </ng-template>
</my-table>
```

The component TestComponent has the selector `my-table`.
It uses the code:

```
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { TableColumnDirective } from '../table-column.directive';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'my-table',
  templateUrl: './test-component.html',
  styleUrl: './test-component.scss'
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChildren(TableColumnDirective) columnList!: QueryList<TableColumnDirective>;
  
  ngAfterContentInit(){
    console.log('column template list');
    console.log(this.columnList.toArray());
  }
}
```

This is, as far as I can tell, identical to the code proposed by Aleš Doganoc in his answer.

My expectation is, that in the method `ngAfterContentInit`, the member `this.columnList` should return the templates which have the directive tableColumn.
However, the collection is always empty.

The console output shows:

```
test-component.ts:15 column template list
test-component.ts:16 Array(0)
```

My test project is on GitHub at:
https://github.com/PhilJollans/content-children-demo

And available on Stackblitz at:
https://stackblitz.com/github.com/PhilJollans/content-children-demo

What am I doing wrong?

*Background information:

I am trying to make a working version of the component [ngx-property-grid](https://github.com/mokeyish/ngx-property-grid), which is no longer being maintained.

This component uses this technique to enumerate templates.*

Comment: Can you please fix the link to the Stack Blitz?

Comment: Can you try again? Sorry, I am new to StackBlitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to achieve what you're looking for:

[image]

[image]

To achieve this, we need to edit some parts of the code.

**Directive**
I removed the constructor parameter since it was unnecessary and declared the directive as `standalone`:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[tableColumn]',
    standalone: true
})
export class TableColumnDirective {
    constructor() { }
    @Input('columnName') columnName = '';
}
```

**Test.component.html**
To render the HTML content placed inside the `my-table` tag, Angular needs to be informed. This is done using `ng-content`:

```
<h1>This is the temp component</h1>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

I've added some references to the **app.component.ts** :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { TestComponent } from './test/test-component';
import { TableColumnDirective } from './table-column.directive';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        TestComponent,
        CommonModule,
        TableColumnDirective,
    ]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

And finally, the actual HTML part:

```
<my-table>
    <!-- Method A -->
    <h1 tableColumn [columnName]="'firstName'">this template is for column firstName</h1>

    <!-- Method B -->
    <ng-template [ngIf]="true" tableColumn [columnName]="'lastName'">
        <h1>this template is for column lastName</h1>
    </ng-template>

    <!-- Test A -->
    <ng-template [ngIf]="true" tableColumn="test1" let-test1>
        <h1>this template is for column test1</h1>
    </ng-template>

    <!-- Test B -->
    <ng-template tableColumn="test2" let-test2>
        <h1>this template is for column test2</h1>
    </ng-template>
</my-table>
```

As you can see, I've provided four scenarios. The first two work as expected, while the other two don't. Let me explain why.

**Method A**
There isn't much to say honestly here. If you append a directive to an HTML tag, you can use the directive's property just like you would for `@Input`.

**Method B**
This one is essentially your original code, with the addition of `[ngIf]="true"` and passing the column name as a parameter. The reason the input parameter is the same as in the first case is because of that. The `[ngIf]="true"` is necessary because Angular doesn't render the `<ng-template>` by default. For this example, I've just set it to true, but there are better ways to achieve this, such as using `ng-container`. You can find more details on `ng-template` [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template).

**Test A**
This example kind of works and kind of doesn't. You can see the `h1` being rendered, but you won't get the directive's reference since we're passing data in the wrong way. `tableColumn="test1" let-test1` doesn't have any meaning in this context. So the `ContentChildren` in the `test.component.ts` understands that there is a DOM element, but it doesn't recognize it as the directive.

**Test B**
As I mentioned in Method B, `ng-templates` aren't rendered by default, so you won't see it in the UI or in the `ContentChildren` directive's scope. The reason you see it in the entry list - the last entry - is too complicated to explain here.

If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. What really surprises me, is that leaving out the Import for TableColumnDirective, did not result in a compilation error.

Comment: Mh, that's strange. In my tests removing the import did led to a compilation error. Anyway, you're welcome. Happy coding.