# table, thead and tbody component breaks the layout of the table when assemble together

Tags: angular, angular8

when i create separately components for `table` and `thead` and `tbody` dissembling in a parent page, the table totally breaks.

don't know how to fix it.

table component:

```
<table>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</table>
```

thead component:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Someple header</th>
    <th>Someple header</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

tbody component:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>sample data1</td>
    <td>sample data2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

when put togather:

```
<app-table>
  <app-thead></app-thead>
  <app-tbody></app-tbody>
</app-table>
```

But it breaks the table. all are arranged as inline element. How to fix it?

[Live URL please resize window](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqkk6j)

Comment: if you check the html result you can see:
`<body>
  <my-app>
    <app-table>
      <table>
        <app-thead>
          <thead>...</thead>
        </app-thead>
        <app-tbody>
          <tbody>...</tbody>
        </app-tbody>
      </table>
    </app-table>
  </my-app>
</body>`

As solution I proposed you to use TemplateRef

Comment: @Myugen - can you share a sample or tutorial about templateRef? how that can be handled this scenario?

Comment: That question was solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631813/angular-pass-multiple-templates-to-component

Comment: @3gwebtrain What exactly are you trying to achieve with this `<app-table>` as opposed to a regular `<table>`?

Comment: @Taurayi - creating dynamic table by passing header array and body array separately and require to keep as sublease with multiple values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the table element, you will see it is rendered like this

```
<table>
  <app-thead>...</app-thead>
  <app-tbody>...</app-tbody>
</table>
```

This itself is not a valid HTML. You cannot have any other wrapper for `tbody` / `thead` other than `table`. This is why your table is breaking, it is excepting `tbody` but instead it gets `app-tbody` and doesn't know what to do with it. I'd suggest not creating separate components for body and head of an table, or if you really have to do it you can like this:

**Solution:** **Using attribute selector**

In your `app-table`, `app-thead`, and `app-tbody` components convert the selector to attribute selector.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-table]'
  ...
})
```

After you do it in all places, you will load your custom table like this:

```
<table app-table>
  <thead app-thead></thead>
  <tbody app-tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Also make sure to remove `<table>`, `<tbody>`, and `<thead>` wrappers from your custom components.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bj8gka)

Comment: what is the workaround for this? In my app I have no of tables, I would like to save time here..

Comment: Hey, guys, maybe a different approach can be of use here. Take a look what @angular/component guys do at this specific part of their datepicker (look at the `mat-calendar-body` component - yeah, it's not just a directive, it brings in the body view to the component): https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/month-view.html

Comment: @3gwebtrain Please check it again, I've updated with a better solution. Also provided the stackblitz

Comment: @Dino - it works, but how can i pass data to `attrb` components?

Comment: Same way as you used to. With @Input

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I think you just need to replace the html for your `TableComponent`, `TheadComponent` and `TbodyComponent` components with just a `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag. Then you would set the display property on the `<app-table>`, `<app-thead>` and `<app-tbody>` to `table`, `table-header-group` and `table-row-group` respectively by using the `:host` selector. The code would look like the following:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  styles: [`:host { display:table; }`]
})
export class TableComponent {}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-thead',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  styles: [`:host { display:table-header-group; }`]
})
export class TheadComponent {}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tbody',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  styles: [`:host { display:table-row-group; }`]
})
export class TbodyComponent {}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
      <app-table>
        <app-thead>Thead</app-thead>
        <app-tbody>Tbody</app-tbody>
      </app-table>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, 
    TableComponent, 
    TheadComponent,
    TbodyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The code will then output as follows:

```
<app-table>
  <app-thead>Thead</app-thead>
  <app-tbody>Tbody</app-tbody>
</app-table>
```